# How to fix Stuck at Loading API

Tags: node.js

I have a code I want to fix why it is stuck at loading screen.

Code is here: https://github.com/Speedevs/speedevs.github.io

I have tried changing the socket server in "config" folder but it seems to be stuck at Loading screen.
I am trying to use this code here: https://github.com/forkdelta any way to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share code causing problem here instead of github link. You can read more https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is the main.json in the config folder I am trying to fix it but it wouldn't work

Comment: I want to use Forkdelta API to fix it or create my API but can't Integra forkdelta API inside it